# Display ACF woocommerce product variation value to frontend

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, product-variations

I managed to have ACF product variation configured. Reference: [Here](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/acf-on-product-variations-almost-works/)

What made me confused is how to display those repeater fields that I added on woo variation products to frontend. I tried this code below but no luck. Can someone help me on this?

```
global $variation_id;

  $specifications_variation = get_field('specifications_variation', $variation_id);
  foreach ($specifications_variation as $sv) {
    $sv_label = $sv['label'];
    $sv_value = $sv['value'];
    echo $sv_label . ' - ' . $sv_value;
  }
```

Comment: It would be good to know what fields you have in your repeater setup. In this example, within your repeater field, do you have two fields called Label & Value? If not, expand your repeater field, and look at the sub fields, use the name values from each of these subfields to output the related data.

Comment: Hi @LukeChaffey thats right I have label and value fields inside the repeater that is named specifications_variation... I am not sure in this line: get_field('specifications_variation', $variation_id); ... there must be $post->ID.. I am not sure

Comment: Blows my theory then. Maybe try hardcoding the ID momentarily to ensure the value is coming through?

Comment: didnt work... any idea?

Comment: Sounds like the data didn't save properly then. Just to confirm, are you using this snippet to save the data? https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/acf-on-product-variations-almost-works/#post-83953

Comment: Yes thats right.. I used that snippet.

Comment: If you have database access (like phpMyAdmin), it would be worth looking in the wp_postmeta table to confirm that when the post_id is your variation ID, do the fields + expected values show.

If they do, I'm not sure where to go from here (other than custom coding a database call). If they don't, try search the meta_value field for a value you expect to be stored and find out what ID it's attaching itself too.

Answer (score 1):

I have finally solved it.. Thanks everyone.

```
$variations = $product->get_available_variations();
foreach ( $variations as $key => $value ) {
    $specifications_variation = get_field('specifications_variation', $value['variation_id']);
    foreach ($specifications_variation as $sv) {
      $sv_label = $sv['label'];
      $sv_value = $sv['value'];
      echo $sv_label . ' - ' . $sv_value . '<br>';
    }
  }
```